# Why Google Maps API returns ZERO_RESULTS if the browser is on a machine located in some countries?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

If I go at this URL with my computer in France I get the good result (even in private mode, not connected to Google) :
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=&components=postal_code:1400|country:BE&key=xxxxx

If I go to the same URL with an other computer not localized in France (eg my server in Switzerland or with Tor Browser), it returns ZERO_RESULTS

The URL is exacly the same... Any idea ? Thanks !

Comment: I can geocode this with an IP in Switzerland. Check your API key restrictions.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. API key is not the problem as other requests (with other address, but same key and from the same machine) works. The solution is Xomena answer, by adding `&region=BE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue and it is tracked in Google issue tracker as bug:

[4-digit postal codes are hard to geocode (AT, AU, BE, CH, DK, NZ, SI)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/75985322)

If you read the bug you will see that one of proposed workarounds is using the regional biasing in requests with 4-digit postal codes.

Indeed when I execute your request I get ZERO_RESULTS, but when I add a regional bias I get a postal code in response:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code%3A1400%7Ccountry%3ABE&region=BE&key=MY_API_KEY`

I hope a workaround will be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, adding `&region=BE` solves the problem !!